# ValueError: trying to return values from a dataframe corresponding to an inputted ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I'm building this streamlit app, where I want my app to fetch some values from my data based on the inputted ID. But I keep getting this error message;

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

snippet of my code;

```
memberno = st.text_input('Enrollee Member ID')
if memberno:
    policy_start_date = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == memberno, 'PolicyInception']
    policy_end_date = active_enrollees.loc[active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == memberno, 'PolicyExpiry']
    member_utilization = utilization_data.loc[
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] >= policy_start_date) & (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] <= policy_end_date)
        & (utilization_data['MemberNo'] == memberno) & (utilization_data['NewApprovalStatus'] == 'APPROVED')
        ]
    
    st.write(policy_start_date)
```

My expectation is that every time a new ID is entered, I want my code to retrieve some values corresponding to the inputted ID in my dataframe and write it to my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a costume function to retrieve Enrollee data then call the function after your `if memberno:`. **Note:** If user enter an ID that is not found in your dataset the code is will definitely throw an error, so it is a good practice to use [`Errors and Exceptions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to handle the error: 
The `.values[0]` syntax in the code snippet extracts the first *(and in this case only)* value from the pandas Series object and returns it as a scalar value. That was the cause of the error due to the absence of `.values[0]` in your code.

```py
def get_member_data(memberno):
    policy_start_date = active_enrollees.loc[
        active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == memberno, 'PolicyInception'].values[0]
    policy_end_date = active_enrollees.loc[
        active_enrollees['MemberNo'] == memberno, 'PolicyExpiry'].values[0]
    member_utilization = utilization_data.loc[
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] >= policy_start_date) &
        (utilization_data['EncounterDate'] <= policy_end_date) &
        (utilization_data['MemberNo'] == memberno) &
        (utilization_data['NewApprovalStatus'] == 'APPROVED')
    ]
    return policy_start_date, policy_end_date, member_utilization


memberno = st.text_input('Enrollee Member ID')
if memberno:
    try:
        policy_start_date, policy_end_date, member_utilization = get_member_data(memberno)
        st.write(member_utilization)
    except IndexError:
        st.write("Enrollee Member ID not available")
```